# An Existing Size-Lazy Vector Type In Haskell

Tags: haskell, vector

I'd like to be able to use O(1) amortized addressing with a vector type that grows lazily according to the demanded index.

This could be achieved by using pairing an [`MVector (PrimState m) a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1/docs/Data-Vector-Mutable.html):
with a `PrimRef m [a]` to hold the remainder, using the standard doubling-algorithm for amoritzed O(1) access:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
module LazyVec where

import Control.Monad.Primitive
import Data.PrimRef
import Data.Vector.Mutable (MVector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as M
import Data.Vector (fromList, thaw)
import Control.Monad (forM_)

data LazyVec m a = PrimMonad m => LazyVec (MVector (PrimState m) a) (PrimRef m [a])

-- prime the LazyVec with the first n elements
lazyFromListN :: PrimMonad m => Int -> [a] -> m (LazyVec m a)
lazyFromListN n xs = do
  let (as,bs) = splitAt n xs
  mvec <- thaw $ fromList as
  mref <- newPrimRef bs
  return $ LazyVec mvec mref

-- look up the i'th element
lazyIndex :: PrimMonad m => Int -> LazyVec m a -> m a
lazyIndex i lv@(LazyVec mvec mref) | i < 0     = error "negative index"
                                   | i < n     = M.read mvec i
                                   | otherwise = do
    xs <- readPrimRef mref
    if null xs
      then error "index out of range"
      else do
        -- expand the mvec by some power of 2
        -- so that it includes the i'th index
        -- or ends
        let n' = n * 2 ^ ( 1 +  floor (logBase 2 (toEnum (i `div` n))))
        let growth = n' - n
        let (as, bs) = splitAt growth xs
        M.grow mvec $ if null bs then length as else growth
        forM_ (zip [n,n+1..] as) . uncurry $ M.write mvec
        writePrimRef mref bs
        lazyIndex i lv
  where n = M.length mvec
```

And I could just use my code - but I'd rather reuse someone else's (for one, I haven't tested mine).

Does a vector type with these semantics (lazy creation from a possibly-infinite list, O(1) amortized access) exist in some package?

Comment: You can use `IntMap`, it's O(1).

Comment: @augustss: Using `O(min(n,W))` is an odd choice on that page, it would only matter for extremely small list sizes, which don't follow the rules of big O anyway... But it does appear to be O(1) for lookup.

Comment: augustuss: It's `O(1)` but it lacks the lazy size criteria.  For example `(fromDistinctAscList . zip [0,1..] $ repeat "hi") ! 0` hangs rather than returning `"hi"`.

Comment: @rampion From the documentation in `Data.IntMap.Lazy`: "API of this module is strict in the keys, but lazy in the values." and "The IntMap type itself is shared between the lazy and strict modules".  With a potentially infinite size, you'll never be able to utilize `IntMap` as it is.

Comment: @bheklilr: ok, so it doesn't meet my requirements ("grows lazily according to the demanded index").

Comment: @rampion You're right, it doesn't satisfy the lazy creation criterion.  (And it's only O(1) because log(maxInt) is a constant.)

Comment: You could use a lazily generated trie, which has the same time complexity as `IntMap` (provided the keys are also `Int`s) but would have the laziness you are after. The constant factors would be worse, but since you are looking for laziness anyway, I doubt this is going to be too much of a problem.

Comment: Note, however, that the cost model is different from what I imagine you might be after. If you generate the trie from a list, each time you visit an element for the first time you will traverse the list from the beginning to its location. So for example if you visit the first n elements of the original list in the trie it takes O(n^2). However, revisiting all n of them again takes O(n), as one would hope. That's necessary because you have to unfold the trie, not fold the list. There may be some interesting optimizations possible, but I will have to talk about those later, if interested.

Comment: @JakeMcArthur: it would be relatively easy to first convert the list to something lazy with (log ) access, then build the trie from that, to avoid (²) build time.

Comment: @JakeMcArthur: Looking closer at my current problem, the list I'm using is just `map go [0,1...]` for some function `go :: Int -> a`, so I could use that directly when generating the Trie.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Either I don't understand something, or I don't think you thought that through. Think about how you would build those data structures and in what order things would be forced when you demand the first value from the result.

Comment: @rampion Ah, great! If it's just a function, then I recommend just using one of the existing memoization packages like `MemoTrie` or `data-memocombinators`. They should make it easy.

Comment: @JakeMcArthur: request--values ... ask-trie ... retrieve--values-á-log ... pop--values-from-initial-list. I do think it should work, with ( log ) rather than (²). But if the OP just needs to "array-ise" a `Int -> a` function, it's definitely preferrable to simply use a trie right away.

Comment: @JakeMcArthur: [worked like a charm](http://rampion.github.io/CopyPastePuzzle/), thanks!

Comment: @JakeMcArthur, do you want to make an answer for your `MemoTrie` suggestion? This is one of the highest voted Haskell questions without an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jake McArthur noted in the comments: "If it's just a function, then I recommend just using one of the existing memoization packages like [MemoTrie](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie) or [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators). They should make it easy."